# Is it possible to have a CI badge for a private repo on GitHub?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, circleci

I have a private repository, that uses CircleCI. I can make a badge reflecting the tests passing/failing in the `README.md` with something like:

```
<img src="https://circleci.com/gh/mikemaccana/someapp.svg?style=shield"/>
```

(the markdown equivalent also works).

However looking on the published page on github.com, GitHub seems to convert this URL to something like:

`https://camo.githubusercontent.com/verylongstringofcharacters`

**Is it possible to have a CI status badge for a private repo?**

I'd be OK with changing Circle permission to make the test status publicly available if that was a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few hours later I found the answer - see [Creating Badges for Private Repositories](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/status-badges/#creating-badges-for-private-repositories)

> Create a status API token, go to your Project’s Settings (present on the top right corner) > API Permissions and create a token scoped to Status.
>
> Include the token in the badge code:

```
[![CircleCI](https://circleci.com/<VCS>/<ORG_NAME>/<PROJECT_NAME>.svg?style=svg&circle-token=<YOUR_STATUS_API_TOKEN>)](<LINK>)
```